# Numpy unfilter the data by original indexes

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have multi-dimentional data X and their corresonding labels y. I filter X by classes in the following way;

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.rand(220,22,1125)
y = np.random.randint(4, size=(220))


# Class indexes
index_class0 = np.where(y==0)[0]
index_class1 = np.where(y==1)[0]
index_class2 = np.where(y==2)[0]
index_class3 = np.where(y==3)[0]

# Filtering X by classes
X0 = X[index_class0,:,:]
X1 = X[index_class1,:,:]
X2 = X[index_class2,:,:]
X3 = X[index_class3,:,:]

# Assume some operations are performed on X0-X3
# TODO: reconstruct X using X0-X3, having same class indexes.
```

Now given X0,X1,X2 & X3 and corresponding class indexes, how can I reconstruct X keeping in view that the class order remains same?

Comment: use `np.argwhere` to get indices of the objects, then extract the elements you want to modify, modify them, them put them back using your stored indices for `X0, X1, ...`

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-leraning`or `scikit-learn` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We already know the indices of different classes in the original array. So just make an empty array and put the X's for classes in their correct place.

```
reconstructed_X = np.zeros(X.shape)

reconstructed_X[index_class0] = X0
reconstructed_X[index_class1] = X1
reconstructed_X[index_class2] = X2
reconstructed_X[index_class3] = X3
```

Comment: we have to reconstruct X from X0,X1,X2,X3 and not using X